# Creating pre-defined taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I’m creating a WordPress plugin, that in turn creates a custom post type for MMA fighters. I want to organise fighters by weight class, so though this would be a good use of a custom taxonomy.

I’ve created a weight class taxonomy like this:

```
<?php
register_taxonomy('mma_weight_class', 'mma_fighter', array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'label' => __('Weight Class'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true
));
```

However, this doesn’t seem to yield quite what I want. When I go to add/edit a fighter post, there’s a weight class panel that displays like the following:

[image]

What I’d like instead is a weight class panel like that, but with options (i.e. Lightweight, Middleweight, Heavyweight etc) predefined by my plugin and displayed as a drop-down list, rather than an open input as above where the user can add any ol’ option.

Is it possible to create pre-defined options for a taxonomy like this?

## Update

So, I found the [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function, programmatically added the weight classes, and changed `hierarchical` to `true` in the taxonomy definition. This gets me closer to what I want, as I now have this:

[image]

However, I’d rather they were radios instead of checkboxes (so users could only select one weight class), and that the “+ Add New Category” option wasn’t available, as I only want users to choose from the pre-defined options and not be able to create their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metabox is looking like this because you defined the `'hierarchical' => false` argument, if you set that to `'hierarchical' => true` it'll adopt the categories style metabox, with checkboxes but i think you don't wanna give the oportunity to the users to create sub-categories, because that would be wrong.

You could have 3 approaches here:

1) Set `'hierarchical' => true` but this will enable a fighter be on more than one class

2) [Change the default metabox for this custom post type, replacing the checkboxes for radio buttons](http://webdevstudios.com/2013/07/08/replace-wordpress-default-taxonomy-metabox-with-a-radio-select-metabox/)

3) [Create a custom metabox, with radio buttons too](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies--wp-24779)

Sorry for bad english